Getting 404 on WordPress posts after changing permalinks to HTML
I am trying to switch a website from Blogger to WordPress. There are quite a few posts on the Blogger site, so I'm trying to get the new links to be the same as before. Blogger permalinks all end in .html, so I added this as a custom permalink structure in WordPress:
/%year%/%monthnum%/%postname%.html
However, after doing that, I can access the homepage and the admin panel, but all the posts give me a 404 error (404 Error. Page Not Found.). I've already tried changing the permissions on the .htaccess file to 666 and re-saving the permalinks settings, but that didn't work.
Is there something I'm missing? Any help will be appreciated!
PS: if it matters, this installation is in a subdomain. Also, it is hosted on HostGator.

Does this answer your question? Wordpress Permalinks not working

It sounds like there might be an issue with the permalink settings not being properly recognized by wordpress or with the rewrite rules in the .htaccess file.Here are some steps you can take to troubleshoot the issue:
1.Check the .htacess file:make sure the wordpress has correctly updated the .htaccess file with the necessary rewrite rules.Sometimes,wordpress permissions to update the .htaccess file automatically updating the .htaccess file with the correct rewrite rules.
2.Verify file permissions:Ensure that the .htaccess file has the correct permissions set.setting it to 666 temporarily should allow wordpress to write to it,but you should change it back to 644 after wordpress has updated it.
3.Permalinls settings:Double-check that you`ve correctly set the custom permalink structure in the wordpress admin panel. Sometimes,a small mistake in the structure can lead to unexpected behavior.
4.Flush rewrite rules:sometimes,wordpress needs to flush its rewrite rules to recognize the new permalinks structure.You can do this by visiting the permalinks settings page in the wordpress admin panel and clicking the"Save changes"button without making any changes.
5.Check for conflicts:plugins or themes could be causing conflicts with the permalink structre.Try deactivatin any plugins and switchining to a default wordpress theme temporarily to see if the issue persists.
6.HostGator-specific issues:HostGator sometimes has its own rules or configurations that could affect wordpress installations.You may want to reach out to HostGator`s support for assistance if the issue persists.
if none of these steps resolve the issue,you may need to dig deeper into the server configuration or seek assistance from HostGator`s support team,as there could be server-specific issues causing the problem.

Well, there could be several reasons for this, I'll list the most likely ones

Redirects in .htaccess. Sometimes redirect settings set in
.htaccess or through plugins can conflict with your permanent link
settings, resulting in 404 errors.
Some plugins, especially SEO plugins or URL rewrite management
plugins, can affect how WordPress handles .html URLs. Disabling and
sequentially enabling plugins can help you determine if any of them
are causing the problem.
Sometimes server cache or WordPress caching plugins can store old or
incorrect versions of pages, resulting in 404 errors even though the
pages actually exist.

and

If the server is not configured to handle URLs ending in .html as dynamic pages, WordPress will not be able to handle requests properly. This is usually solved by rewrite rules in the .htaccess file, but if the mod_rewrite module is missing or disabled, URL rewriting will not work.

Hope it helps!
